# Компиляция cocos2dx для Android Studio

Tags: android, ubuntu, cocos2d

Я новичок, поэтому сразу извиняюсь, могу ошибиться в терминологии.
**Стоит задача перенести проект cocos2dx в android studio.**
ОС Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Установила jdk, jre.
Прописала $JAVA_HOME в /etc/environment.
Установила sdk, ndk, ant, cocos.
В .bashrc прописала переменные среды, возможно избыточно.

```
# Add environment variable COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT=/usr/local/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/tools/cocos2d-console/bin
export PATH=$COCOS_CONSOLE_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable COCOS_X_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export COCOS_X_ROOT=/usr/local
export PATH=$COCOS_X_ROOT:$PATH

# Add environment variable COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT for cocos2d-x
export COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT=/usr/local/cocos2d-x-3.15.1/templates
export PATH=$COCOS_TEMPLATES_ROOT:$PATH

export NDK_ROOT=/usr/local/android-ndk-r15c
export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/marchelli/Android/Sdk
export ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS=/home/marchelli/Android/Sdk/tools
export ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS=/home/marchelli/Android/Sdk/platform-tools
export ANT_ROOT=/usr/local/apache-ant-1.10.1/bin

export PATH=$NDK_ROOT:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_TOOLS:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_SDK_PLATFORM_TOOLS:$PATH
export PATH=$ANT_ROOT:$PATH
```

Создала новый проект:

```
~$ cocos new First -p com.firstapp -l cpp -d /home/marchelli/cocos
```

Пытаюсь скомпилировать:

```
~/cocos/First$ cocos compile -p android --android-studio
```

В итоге выдает ошибку:
BUILD FAILED
Total time: 2.651 secs
Stopped 0 worker daemon(s).
Received result Failure[value=org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':First:externalNativeBuildDebug'.] from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=14314, address=[a6a6e3c1-1f8e-4311-a43d-8b8bb54743a9 port:46387, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1503155152471, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=8b8b772a-597e-48ab-844d-3a3e75de6a27,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/marchelli/.gradle/daemon,pid=14314,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:MaxPermSize=256m,-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=RU,-Duser.language=ru,-Duser.variant]} (build should be done).
Error running command, return code: 1.

Пробовала указать API 24 и ниже, в sdk предварительно установила эти платформы.

```
cocos compile -p android --android-studio--ap android-24 --stacktrace --debug
```

То же самое
BUILD FAILED и огромное сообщение ошибки.

**Подскажите, если не решение, то в каком направлении его искать?**

Также, не нашла ответ, что должно было появиться после добавления --stacktrace --debug.

Увидела чуть выше еще ошибку.

```
:First:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED
:First:externalNativeBuildDebug (Thread[Task worker Thread 3,5,main]) completed. Took 1.383 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':First:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /usr/local/android-ndk-r15c/ndk-build with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=/home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/jni/Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=/home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/jni/Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-9 NDK_OUT=/home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=/home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/lib NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION=4.9 APP_PLATFORM=android-13 NDK_MODULE_PATH=/home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d:/home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d/cocos:/home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d/external -j4 NDK_DEBUG=1 /home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi/libMyGame.so}
  Android NDK: android-13 is unsupported. Using minimum supported version android-14.    
  [armeabi] Compile++ thumb: cocos2dxandroid_static <= ProcessCpuTracker.cpp
  /home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp: In function 'std::vector<_CpuInfo> readProcStat()':
  /home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp:69:54: error: 'read' was not declared in this scope
       const int len = read(fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer)-1);
                                                        ^
  /home/marchelli/cocos/First/cocos2d/cocos/platform/android/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.cpp:70:13: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope
       close(fd);
               ^
  make: *** [/home/marchelli/cocos/First/proj.android-studio/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/cocos2dxandroid_static/jni/ProcessCpuTracker.o] Error 1


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка связанна с тем, что в файле `ProcessCpuTracker.cpp` отсутствует `#include <unistd.h>`. Для решения этой проблемы вам необходимо либо понизить версию NDK до r14 или ниже, либо применить [патч](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/17943) для NDK 15 самостоятельно, который будет внесён только в следующих версиях cocos2d-x. Также в файле `Application.mk` добавьте `APP_PLATFORM := android-14`

Comment: Спасибо огромное!! С NDK r14 всё заработало!